# Displaced Simulation on XCode Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Maybe an image is worth thousand words. As in the image below, XCode Simulator does not simulate anything and just show the default home screen, but strange enough, a separate window opens and the contents that should show up on the XCode Simulator showed up in the separate window.

This question is so strange I am completely clueless what happened or even find the correct term to describe the situation. Can anyone inspire me what's going on and what's the correct remedy to it?

Thanks a lot!

Bosco

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running your app with the macOS scheme, so it executes on your Mac (you must have enabled the Mac Catalyst checkbox).

Select an iPhone simulator in the list (top left of Xcode code editor) instead of "My Mac".

---

The target:

[image]

Mac Catalyst:

[image]